# Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected 'object' to be a number in selecting an object from an object list when using ng-options in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, restangular, angularjs-ng-options

I have to generate select options dynamically from the database.

I used, Restangular to generate a projectList, which is a list of all project records from DB..

```
<select 
     ng-model   ="projectLog.project"
     ng-options ="project.name for project in projectLog.allprojectList"> 
</select>
```

It did shown, all the projects name, for me to select. But when i selected any project, then this error occurs,

```
Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected`{"id":1,"name":"SandS","route":"iso_projects","reqParams":null,"restangularized":true,"fromServer":true,"parentResource":null,"restangularCollection":false}` to be a number
```

I use ui-router, Restangular and  select2.

Comment: You are trying to assign an object to a place where angular is expecting a **"number"**. This will help you - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10808

Comment: Can you show your jsfiddle / json data ?

Comment: #Nikhil:  What you mean by, angular is expecting a number. ng-options ="project.name as project.name for project in projectLog.allprojectList"> is not working. But, "project.id as project.name for project in projectList works. Should this be both works for string and number, alike.

Comment: @Loading:  My controller object 'projectList' is a regular javascript object, with name field in it. It is GET'd from DB, using Restangular. Restangular is using 'promises', has to do with the problem, i wonder. And the controller functions works fine.